# Why limiting the liability in the Terms of an App to 150% service fees?

Tags: liability, terms-of-service

A language learning app from a German company states in their Terms the following in their "Limitation of Liability" section:

> We shall be unrestrictedly liable for (a) injury to life, body or health caused by Babbel, its legal representatives or assistants in performance; (b) damage caused intentionally or with gross negligence by Babbel, its legal representatives or assistants in performance; (c) damage resulting from the absence of any guaranteed characteristics; and (d) claims under the German Product Liability Act.

> Our total liability arising out of or in connection with any Order, whether in contract or tort or otherwise shall in no circumstances exceed a sum equal to one hundred and fifty percent (**150%**) of the total Service Fees paid or payable by the User under the relevant Order.

Can anybody tell me why 150%? We talk about subscription fees around 200 EUR maximum, so the exact number does not really matter. Is this an arbitrary number or is there some (German? EU?) law requiring something like this?